# Joomla www enforcing in urls with .htaccess, not working as it should

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, seo

I have a joomla 1.6 website, and I want to enforce a www in the beginning of urls.
I've written the following into htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example\.com [nc]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

What it should do is redirect from example.com/happy_bunnies.html to www.example.com/happy_bunnies.html. Instead it redirects to www.example.com/index.php

---

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example\.com [nc]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com%1 [r=301,nc,l]
```

No idea why the first didn't work, but this one does

Comment: It's strange, didn't you mistakenly put the code at the bottom of .htaccess? are the other redirect working?

Comment: Apparently what made the difference were the ^ $ signs

Comment: I tested my hypothesis, no it works even without the ^ $. Maybe some typo

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried...

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```